# Quicktab Scrolling

Tags: blocks

Is there anyway to set a quicktab to scroll the content within the tab when using a callback?

For example: I have a list of events that I would like to have in a set height tab and then have the opportunity to scroll through like a Twitter / Facebook widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a css thing. You need to right click on your page and select **Inspect Element** then find the name of the div class that has the content within the tab. Then just give it a fixed height and an overflow scroll. For example:

```
.mydiv { height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/woutrav0/4/)